# Rapidly Converging Series for Particular Values of the Gamma Function

Tags: summation, gamma-function, modular-forms

C. H. Brown found some rapidly converging infinite series for particular values of the gamma function
,
$$\frac {\Gamma\left(\tfrac 13\right)^6}{12\pi^4}=\frac 1{\sqrt{10}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac {(6k)!}{k!^3(3k)!}\frac {(-1)^k}{(3\cdot160^3)^k}$$$$\frac {\Gamma\left(\tfrac 14\right)^4}{128\pi^3}=\frac 1{\sqrt u}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac {(6k)!}{k!^3(3k)!}\frac {1}{\big(2\sqrt2\,u^3v^6\big)^k}$$

where $u=273+180\sqrt2,$ and $v=1+\sqrt2$.

> **Questions:**

1. How did C. Brown derive these respective infinite formulas?
2. Can you derive similar formulas for different gamma functions?

I couldn't help but notice that these formulas share a similarity to the *Chudnovsky Algorithm*$$\frac 1\pi=12\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac {(6k)!}{k!^3(3k)!}\frac {545140134k+13591409}{640320^{k+1/2}}$$So perhaps Brown used the J-function and modular forms to derive the values?$$j(\tau)=\frac 1q+744+196884q+21493760q^2+\cdots$$

Comment: Looks somewhat like a BBP-style formula, the kind Ramanujan would solve in his sleep using Hypergeometric functions. I'm willing to bet the sums were discovered by a computer, and educated guess as to what such a sum might look like, and a lot of case checking until the computer found a likely match that was *then* formally proved

Comment: Reference to the Brown results please.

Comment: @Somos Oh lol I just found it on Wikipedia. But all Wikipedia does is present the result, but not a proof. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I believe Brown may have been experimenting with the j-function. I’m curious though, since there are infinitely many $j(\tau)$, that he focused only on these two. The others are potentially interesting as well.

Answer (score 4):

That Wikipedia link
points to
http://www.iamned.com/math/
which has a large number
of amazing formulae.

That, in turn,
points to
http://iamned.com/math/infiniteseries.pdf
titled
"An Algorithm for the Derivation of Rapidly Converging Infinite Series for Universal Mathematical Constants".

Answer (score 3):

[Back in 2011](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326022033/https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0026), I empirically found the general family for this type of formulas. The OP was right when he compared them to the Chudnovsky algorithm which uses the *j-function* $j(\tau)$.

---

**I. j-function**

The first has $j\big(\frac{1+\sqrt{-27}}{2}\big) = -3\times160^3.$

The second has $j(\sqrt{-16}) = 2\sqrt2\,(273+180\sqrt2)^3(1+\sqrt2)^6.$

A third should be $j(\sqrt{-6}) = 12^3\,(5+2\sqrt2)^3(1+\sqrt2)^2.$

---

**II. Watson triple integrals**

Brown's formulas can be connected to the *"Watson triple integrals"*. (He missed the third one though.) Let,

\begin{align}
I_1 &= \frac{1}{\pi^3} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx \, dy \, dz}{1-\cos x \cos y \cos z}\\
I_2 &= \frac{1}{\pi^3} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx \, dy \, dz}{3-\cos x \cos y -\cos x \cos z -\cos y \cos z}\\
I_3 &= \frac{1}{\pi^3} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx \, dy \, dz}{3-\cos x -\cos y -\cos z}
\end{align}

then,

\begin{align}
\frac{4^{4/3}}{3^2}\color{red}{I_2} &= \frac 1{\sqrt{10}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac {(6k)!}{k!^3(3k)!}\frac {(-1)^k}{(3\cdot160^3)^k} = \frac {\Gamma\left(\tfrac 13\right)^6}{12\pi^4}\\
\frac{1}{2^5}\color{red}{I_1} &= \frac 1{\sqrt u}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac {(6k)!}{k!^3(3k)!}\frac {1}{\big(2\sqrt2\,u^3\,(1+\sqrt2)^6\big)^k} = \frac {\Gamma\left(\tfrac 14\right)^4}{128\pi^3}\\
\frac{1}{2^{1/2}}I_3 &= \frac 1{\sqrt w}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac {(6k)!}{k!^3(3k)!}\frac {1}{\big(12^3w^3\,(1+\sqrt2)^2\big)^k} = \frac {\Gamma\left(\tfrac 1{24}\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac 5{24}\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac 7{24}\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac {11}{24}\right)}{32\sqrt3\,\pi^3}
\end{align}

where $u=273+180\sqrt2,$ and $w=5+2\sqrt2$.

---

**III. Gamma functions**

For the first, given $\tau = \big(\frac{1+\sqrt{-d}}{2}\big)$ where $d>3$, a general formula is the simple *sum-product identity*,

$$\frac1{\big({-j(\tau)}\big)^{1/6}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(6n)!}{(3n)!(n!^3)} \frac1{\big(j(\tau)\big)^n} = \frac1{(2\pi)d}\prod_{m=1}^{d-1} \Big[\Gamma\big(\tfrac m d\big)\Big]^{\big(\frac{-d}{m}\big)}$$

where the gamma functions's exponent $\big(\frac{-d}{m}\big)$ is the *Kronecker symbol*. For example, let $d = 7$, so $j\big(\frac{1+\sqrt{-7}}{2}\big)=-15^3$. Thus,

$$\frac1{\big({15^3}\big)^{1/6}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(6n)!}{(3n)!(n!^3)} \frac1{\big({-15^3}\big)^n} = \frac1{7(2\pi)}\frac{\Gamma\big(\tfrac17\big)\Gamma\big(\tfrac27\big)\Gamma\big(\tfrac47\big)}{\Gamma\big(\tfrac37\big)\Gamma\big(\tfrac57\big)\Gamma\big(\tfrac67\big)} $$

and so on.

Comment: [Related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61679/4781) on the Watson triple integrals.

Comment: I find these results quite amazing and also I'm upset that I am the only one who up voted this while I got votes for just pointing to some links.

Comment: @martycohen Thanks, Marty. With the speed that posts move, the people who appreciate such posts probably didn’t see it.

Comment: I saw it, thanks to the comment from Tito. Happy I saw it too :) really pretty results

Comment: These formulas are the hypergeometric series for $(2K(k)/\pi)^2$ in terms of Ramanujan's class invariants $G_n, g_n$ namely $(2K/\pi)^2=(1-4G_n^{-24})^{-1/2}{}_3F_2(1/6,5/6,1/2;1,1;-27G_n^{48}/(G_n^{24} -4)^3)$ and $(2K/\pi)^2=(k'^4+16k^2)^{-1/2}{}_3F_2(1/6,5/6,1/2;1,1;27g_n^{48}/(g_n^{24}+4)^3)$. The first series in question is for $G_{27}$ and second series is for $g_{16}$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for the info. In the webaerchive link, I also noticed the connection to $K(k)$ but used gamma functions above since the OP inquired about them. I used $\tau = \frac{1+\sqrt{-n}}{2}$, hence $G_n$, but your formula using $g_n$ fills in the other half. **P.S.** As you can tell, the third series (in my answer) is $g_6$.

Comment: I checked your webarchive link in detail and I find it strongly related to Berndt's paper ["Ramanujan's theory of elliptic functions to  alternative bases"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2155035). The earliest development was done by Borwein brothers who found series for $(2K/\pi)^2$ in terms of ${}_3F_{2}(r,1-r,1/2;1,1;c_r(k))$ for $r=1/2,1/3,1/4,1/6$ and suitable functions $c_r(k) $. Later Berndt found all this hidden in notebooks of Ramanujan and he wrote his paper based on that. In particular it should help to find an expression for $r_{3A}(\tau)$ given in your link.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks! Yes, i was having trouble with the case $r = 1/3$. Maybe I should revisit these formulas.

Comment: If you have access to Browein's book "Pi and the AGM", it contains the hypergeometric series for $(2K/\pi)^2$. The formula is complicated for $r=1/3$ and you may details in the book from page 177-191